# Why do I get an out of bounds error on an array inside a while loop even after using the decrement operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

In the C++ code below, I got an **out of bounds error on the last line**.

```
int n;cin>>n;
int a[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   cin>>a[i];
while(n--)
   {a[n]-a[n-1];}
```

There shouldn't be an issue since in the while loop, n will first get decremented and then it will start executing the code in the loop.

I have run it on multiple IDEs and it ran fine, but gave me an out of bounds error when I tried to submit the solution on codeforces.

Comment: `int a[n];` is not legal if `n` is not constant, by the way. Anyway, it's undefined behaviour, so "ran fine" is relative, maybe you got lucky.

Comment: `while (n--)` goes round the loop with `n` equal to zero, so `a[n-1]` is out of bounds.

Comment: *"n will first get decremented and then it will start executing the code in the loop"* -- You skipped mentioning when the conditional of your loop is checked (a rather important step when it comes to avoiding out-of-bounds in a loop).

Answer (score 2):

`n--` returns `n` prior to the decrement.

Thus, the last iteration has `n == 0`, meaning `a[n - 1]` accesses element -1, a clear case of undefined-behavior due to out-of-bounds array-access.

Changing to `--n` would give the adjusted variable instead, and thus "fix" the code.

As an aside, variable-length-arrays are not a standard C++ feature, though many C++ compilers accept it as an extension imported from C99.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `n--`. Yes, it decrements `n`, but it evaluates to the value of `n` *before* the decrement. I.e., by the time `n--` evaluates to `0` to break the loop, the loop already ran with `n` equal to `0`. This causes `a[n-1]` to be out of bounds.

A very simple change will make it work, though: use `--n`. This evaluates to the value of `n` *after* the decrement, as so will break the loop as soon as `n` becomes `0`.